# How do I add a local upstream to git?

Tags: git, github

I have two GitHub-hosted clones set up.  One is a readonly clone of the repository, the other is a read/write clone of my fork.  I have changes I intend to submit a pull request for on the fork clone.  But to test, I want to merge it locally into my readonly clone, which has changes I did a while back that aren't fit for consumption.

**How do I set up one clone to be able to merge from the other clone's feature branch?**  I think it's simply setting up an upstream, but using git is probably the hardest thing I've ever tried to do, and so I reach out to you for help.  I'm sure there are 12 ways to do it, all equally bizarre. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about 12 ways to do it, but the easiest would be `git remote add other /path/to/other/repository`. Then you can `git fetch other` and/or `git push other`. There are some other things you can do to set up specific branches you want to push/fetch from, but adding another remote (even though it's not remote) is the way to start.

Comment: Thanks!  I did the git remote, then the git fetch other, followed by a `git merge other/new_feature_branch`.  Perfect.